# How to dim an image keeping transparency untouched with CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

Normal approach to dimming an image suggested everywhere is to change it's opacity attribute and display something dark under it. However, my image has transparency and is on white background. So I want to keep the background under transparent parts of image white, only making darker the pixels that have color. Is this possible to do in CSS (preferably) or JS?

EDIT: Sample images https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoAiS.jpg

Example image:

[image]

Comment: Make another image that is essentially a silhouette of yours, having all of the opaque pixels as black, position it as directly below the original, and then change the opacity of the original image.

Comment: @PitaJ Well I could as well just make dimmed image and just display it instead, but I have like 50 of these images, and they are subject to change, so this will be time-consuming, but I guess I'll have to do this if there's no better solution.

Comment: You could convert it to a canvas and dim it in the canvas.

Comment: I think this is very likely possible with a `canvas` element, but since I don't know much about it, I'd rather not try to come up with an answer for this. Look around the web with terms like `drawing an image on html canvas with opacity`.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the image first so we can see what we'reworking with but the `filter` property might offer some options?

Comment: @Paulie_D Added sample images to the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a relatively new CSS property `filter` which might achieve what you are after.

The `brightness` option seems to be what you are after.

EDIT - Added interim support for FF via URL

[**JSFiddle Demo (with brightness and contrast options)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/warbe532/4/)

**CSS**

```
img {
width:250px;
}
#one:hover {
    -webkit-filter:brightness(50%);
    -moz-filter:brightness(50%);
    filter: url(#brightness); /* required for FF */
    filter:brightness(50%);
}
#two:hover {
    -webkit-filter:contrast(50%);    
    -moz-filter:contrast(50%);
     filter: url(#contrast);
    filter:contrast(50%);
}
```

[**MDN on Filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Support is non-IE see [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/css-filters)

FF support (at the time of writing) requires definition of an SVG filter

**Brightness @ 50%**

```
<svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <filter id="brightness">
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope=".5" />
            <feFuncG type="linear" slope=".5" />
            <feFuncB type="linear" slope=".5" />
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>

</svg>
```

**Contrast @ 200%**

```
<svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="contrast">
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope="2" intercept="-(0.5 * 2) + 0.5" />
            <feFuncG type="linear" slope="2" intercept="-(0.5 * 2) + 0.5" />
            <feFuncB type="linear" slope="2" intercept="-(0.5 * 2) + 0.5" />
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably what I'm looking for, but your fiddle doesn't work in latest Firefox.

Comment: Interesting, it was working in FF30 but not when I updated to FF31.

Comment: @KonstantinPereyaslov Added FF support based on MDN article

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use javascript instead of css, it's not especially difficult to do this with the HTML canvas. You simply hand the canvas an image object and then grab the context which will allow you to loop through and manipulate the individual color channels. Of course it breaks completely with no JS.

```
function darkenImage(imageObj, percentage) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('aCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x =0;
    var y =0;

    context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y);

    var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
    var data = imageData.data;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
       // red
       data[i] = percentage * data[i];
       // green
       data[i + 1] = percentage * data[i + 1];
       // blue
       data[i + 2] =  percentage * data[i + 2] ;
    }

    // overwrite original image
    context.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
  }
var anImage = new Image();
anImage.onload = function() {
    darkenImage(this, .5);
  };
anImage.crossOrigin = 'http://api.imgur.com/crossdomain.xml'
anImage.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/GnMumrk.png';
```

This is a naive calculation to make it easy, but as you can see it wouldn't be hard to alter it to something a little fancier. Since we don't touch the alpha channel, the transparency remains untouched.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markm/kwsogrdt/
(the browser complains about the cross origin image at least in safari which is why the second to last line is there.)

Comment: Im a fan of this one because it'll be the most cross-browser for this sort of behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be by using new CSS `mask` property (currently fully supported only by webkit) on the div with the darkening.

```
.dim {
  display: none;
  /*Also position it above the image*/
 }

.dim:hover {
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.5;
 -webkit-mask: url(image.png) top left / cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of instead of changing the opacity of the image, say putting a div on top of the image with the same size as the image, opacity of 0.3 and a background color of black.

This may not be what you are looking for though its food for thought.

Gab

Comment: And how is this going to solve anything? Transparent pixels of image are still going to be dimmed.