# Filter chains in browsers other than Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently discovered the CSS 3 filtering options of Chrome, which allowed me to do some fancy stuff that I otherwise wouldn't be able to do. However, it now turns out that this isn't quite compatible with Firefox and Opera (don't know about IE and Safari, as it is a hassle to install these on my Linux machine). I searched a bit on the net, but I can not find a good work around for this. I do find some cross browser work arounds for individual filters, but I really need to have the following work in all major browsers:

```
   -webkit-filter: contrast(0.5) sepia(100%) invert(100%) hue-rotate(350deg) brightness(2.5);
   filter: contrast(0.5) sepia(100%) invert(100%) hue-rotate(350deg) brightness(2.5);
```

I would be fine with a Javascript library that can do this, but I also cannot find something like this. Does anyone have any ideas on this subject?

Comment: You might want to review this [**MDN on CSS filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) and this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092391/how-to-dim-an-image-keeping-transparency-untouched-with-css-or-js/25092894#25092894) where I looked into a couple of properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good explanation of filters in CSS. Under "Availability in modern browsers" there's more information about the browser compatibility. According to that website your code should work.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, this article says that all filters are just supported in Chrome. It does say a word about -moz and -o prefix, but for me these do not work. I did find out about FabricJS, but I would prefer something simpler.